# How can I post an answer with many links, or earn that privilege without being allowed to post such quality answers?

Tags: support, hyperlinks, new-users

I cannot submit my answer to 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424752/

I am aware that my reputation is low. Also, spam posting is discouraged. 
My answer includes a compilation of Android graphing libraries, with links, so fellow hackers do not have to Google each and every one of them.

I believe this answer is superior to the current answers, because it is updated to 03/2012 and covers more than 90% of all Android charting libraries.

How can I post the answer, or how can I increase my reputation without being able to post quality answers? The old school websites included just a bunch of links to other places, I am an old man!

Alternative solution would be to blog it, and just post a link to my blog, which is not optimal.

Comment: As an aside: the answers (apparently) being outdated indicates that the very question [is not a good fit](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) for the Q&A site that Stack Overflow wants to be, and might be closed, [locked](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for) or even deleted. Also, just a link to your blog [is certainly not wanted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers).

Comment: Like said on a comment to the answer, just post away with only two links and leave a comment asking to turn the other "links" into real links - somebody will surely do so. :)

Answer (score 5):

The reputation limit for the [new user restrictions](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/new-user) is only `10`.

Gaining `10` rep is easy. You could, for example:

- Answer any other question. A single upvote will give you the reputation you need.
- Post your answer with only two of the links, wait for it to get upvoted and edit it to incorporate the rest.

Comment: Ad 2): mangle the remaining links to not be links. Like: remove the http:// part. Then after getting the upvotes, change it. Or someone with some more reputation might already change it for you.

Answer (score 2):

Ah, I see the problem! That question [doesn't belong on Stack Overflow in the first place](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask). That's why the system is not optimized to deal with new users posting answers to it. It should be closed as "not constructive" shortly. Thanks for bringing this to our attention.

You should be able to find plenty of other questions to answer that *don't* require you to post more than one (if any) links.

Or, failing that, do as [Kate suggests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/127679/153008). I also frequently make edits to posts to incorporate links and images from new users with insufficient reputation.

Answer (score 1):

I frequently come across questions which contain a link to a picture because the user can't post pictures, or contain links that aren't links because the user can only post two links. It takes only a moment to look at the picture and confirm it's not spam, then edit it into the post, or follow the link and confirm it's not spam, then edit it into the post as a link.

Therefore I would advise you to do the best you can with the rep you have, and someone will edit it for you, or you'll gain rep from your best effort that will enable you to come back yourself and make it better.