# Why doesn't "Hidden features of Python" show up in search results?

Tags: support, closed-questions, search

When I [search for "python"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python), I see other closed questions, but not [Hidden features of Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python). Why isn't it shown? How can I search for it and other hidden highly-voted questions?

Comment: That's taken care of.  Just go to reddit.com and type "python hidden features" and take the first hit.  They need the help, you know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was given a [historical lock](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for), which means that it no longer appears in certain lists.

When you search for "python", your search is [automatically redirected](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/stack-overflow-search-now-61-less-crappy/) to the list of questions tagged [python](/questions/tagged/python) because it is one of Stack Overflow's top 40 tags. Questions with historical locks apparently don't appear there anymore, but they *are* supposed to appear in searches.

You can work around this by searching for [questions both tagged as and containing "python"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5Bpython%5D%20%22python%22). The quotation marks stop the system from converting it to a tag search.

Comment: Or just search for `hidden features of python` -- anything that ends up on the search page and not a tag page

Comment: thanks the containing "python" trick is what i was looking for.