# Searches on historically locked questions by locked status and <tag> do not work

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, search, historical-lock

While removing the [hidden-features](/questions/tagged/hidden-features) tag, I noticed that searching on a tag, as well as with the `locked` status filter does not work.

See here for the [hidden-features](/questions/tagged/hidden-features) tag:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bhidden-features%5D+locked%3A1 (25, these are all locked)

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bhidden-features%5D+locked%3A0 (25, um, these are all locked, WTF?)

It also show's up in the tag auto-complete, which I can't tell if it is a bug or not (the [FAQ entry on historical locks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126631/140951) states that it won't show up in *question* searches, but this isn't a question search).

[image: Why are these tags still here?!?!?!?!]

That said, please fix the search for using a tag combined with the `locked` status.

Additionally, if a question *is* historically locked, then it shouldn't count towards the tag count in the auto-complete list when suggesting tags.  For popular tags such as [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) and whatnot, we're not in danger of someone *not* finding that tag.  For tags which are honeypots of crap questions, those tags shouldn't be there in the first place, and we shouldn't be suggesting those tags to people asking new questions.

Comment: On a side note, hurry up and fix this, it's screwing up the cleanup. =)

Comment: We need a flag-as-stackexchange-attention on meta. It should display the bat signal for devs instead of being shunted to the flag queue.  But that's never going to be implemented due to possibilities/likeliness of abuse.

Comment: Strip all tags.

Comment: @yoda I'd like to, but if I can't find the damn things to begin with, I can't strip them.

Comment: you should be able to use http://stackoverflow.com/annotated-posts for your clean up efforts while we sort this out.

Comment: @waffles How so?  I can't filter that on tags...

Answer (score 2):

The search is working correctly, though admittedly in a *very* unintuitive way here.  With `locked:0`, you're finding **answers** that are not locked (remember answers *can* be locked) on those questions.

To do what you're after right now, slap a `is:question` on there. The behavior will improve for this case in the future, but it's part of a much larger set of search changes in the pipe so it won't be ready today.

Comment: But, answers don't have tags?  And the returned links don't take me to the answer, but the *question*.

Comment: @casperOne - sure they do, the tags of the question apply to the answers as well.  As for the links, yes they go to the page, I said it wasn't intuitive... Expect this behavior to be adjusted in the coming weeks.