# Not finding the answer panel on a locked question

Tags: support, locked-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a historical lock, and what is it used for?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for)

I want to provide an answer for the following question
[What are your favorite extension methods for C#? (codeplex.com/extensionoverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271398/what-are-your-favorite-extension-methods-for-c-codeplex-com-extensionoverflow?page=5&tab=votes#tab-top)

This is one of the popular questions, and answers are frozen. Does that mean no additional answers can be provided?

I believe questions such as this should never be closed since they are related to language features, which evolve over time. There is always the possibility of new answers.

Comment: You have read the big notice at the top of that question, I assume? Questions like those are simply not a good fit for a Q&A. Stack Overflow has evolved away from them.

Comment: you just happen to look at Stack Overflow through a [broken window](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/broken-windows "Existing inappropriate questions...")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the reason the message was locked in the text description:

> This question exists because it has historical significance, but it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site, so please do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here. This question and its answers are frozen and cannot be changed. More info: FAQ.

It's locked precisely because we don't want new answers.  In a sense, we don't even want the existing answers.  But because of the *historical significance* of the question and answers, it was locked, rather than deleted.

If someone were to ask the exact same question today, it would be closed as 'not constructive'.

Answer (score 5):

> Does that mean no additional answers can be provided.

Yes.

Also, what is your favorite flavor of ice cream?

Comment: >>Also, what is your favorite flavor of ice cream? 
And how is that related to original question. Dont you think i am human

If you have downvoted, can i ask why? I have something to add to the  question mentioned, and there was no way so this question.

Comment: Too bad, you can't. And, it is related to the original question in that it asks "What is your favorite ______?", and as interesting as it is, that kind of question simply isn't appropriate for our site anymore.

Comment: Understood from explanation of your, and Flimzy. 

I was under different impression previously.
Thanks

Comment: Mint chocolate chip. Thanks for asking!

Comment: I find the texture is more important than the flavor.  A rich chocolate full of ice crystals is not as good as a weak vanilla with a smooth and creamy mouth feel.

Comment: Unicorn Meat. Ben & Jerry's said they would start distributing it early next quarter.