# Why does the RegEx answer keep getting locked?

Tags: discussion, answers

[This answer by bobince](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/561731) is **very** famous on Stack Overflow.

Was it locked due it being heavily edited?

It was locked due to a *Content Dispute*, but it doesn't say over what.

Is there a way to just block the editing of the answer, since a lock also blocks:

- Upvotes
- Comments

Maybe we just do not want any more uselss comments, but why can't we allow voting for this ***amazing*** answer?

## OR

Can we just lock the question since it already has many answers which will help future users?

Comment: Yeah, a post score of 4432 just doesn't do justice. 4433 is the least it should have.

Comment: @balpha or at least `4444` ^_^

Comment: I'm not sure what all the recent locking/unlocking business is about, but it has been defaced in the past.  It's been flagged 19 times as well.  Some people don't get the joke.

Comment: @BilltheLizard that is what it seems. Wonder why this question is getting downvoted? I guess people *like* that answer being locked?

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA I guess so.  I know it gets linked to inappropriately (in cases where regex *can* be used) quite a lot, so maybe it has received a little too much attention.

Comment: This post does not bode well for your chances in the [election](http://stackoverflow.com/election/3#post-10899121).  If elected, would you unlock and vote on that post?

Comment: @KevinVermeer I would have to confer with the other moderators. Weird that there is so much backlash to this post though.

Comment: I think the entire Question should be locked permanently. 62 answers and half of the ones on the front page don't really answer the question. We'd do better with a new Question held to current standards, and preserving this one as an artifact.

Comment: It's not an amazing _answer_. It's awesome, hilarious, a work of art, but as far as answers go it's a typical "don't do that, do this instead" answer. I think part of the backlash is because people are quite bored discussing the same relics over and over again, and part of it because there's absolutely no reason for people to keep upvoting a +4432 answer. Would anyone notice if it went to +4450? And if they did, would it make any difference?

Comment: @YannisRizos so lock the question! why lock the individual answer, the qusetion already has waaaay too many answers!

Comment: Agreed, and if you put that in your question I'll reverse my vote.

Comment: @YannisRizos it has been added

Comment: @JeremyBanks I added that to my question now.

Comment: +1 for locking the question, and for the curiosity, a mod hopeful trying to understand why an answer is locked is a good thing.

Comment: @BilltheLizard All the knee-jerk linking to a non-helpful non-answer has become Pavlovian.  It doesn’t help people, and it is downright rule to flip them off that way.  Better by far to link to [something that shows them how](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/471272), while explaining you probably don’t want to do that.  ***Zalgo delenda est.***

Comment: @tchrist I'm with you on this. The "<center> cannot hold" answer is up to 90 flags. I grew tired of it long ago. I'll happily promote a more helpful answer.

Comment: @BilltheLizard I’m doing my best, but [pugnacious jokers like these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24105763/how-to-use-regexp-to-match-all-characters-between-html-tags?noredirect=1#comment37193225_24105763) just make it harder. They seem to think they’re doing something useful or helpful, and they are not.  ***Zalgo delenda est.***

Comment: @tchrist The issue with the answer "something that shows them how", is that it doesn't do that at all. Perl is a Turing complete language, the parser presented in the answer uses more than just Regex in PERL, it uses the PERL language constructs themselves, including for loops, function calls, if statements and other conditionals. In reality, it is just a parser that uses regex, which is standard practice for parsers. The post would only have been accurate if he had made a single regex that parses HTML, a task for which there is likely no regex library capable of doing.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The answer was locked because it kept getting defaced.  It remains on the site (in spite of its dubious nature), because it is a colorful part of Stack Overflow history, and merits preservation.

What is the basis for locking the question?  To do that, there needs to be some compelling reason for locking it, and I don't see one.  See [What is a historical lock, and what is it used for?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for)

Comment: Not a historical lock. But a general lock (if that exists).

Comment: What for?  It's already protected against 1-rep bikeshedders.  Locking it would just prevent the ability to maintain it.

Comment: `since it already has many answers which will help future users`

Comment: If it were *actually maintained*, fine, but it hasn't been. A ton of the highly-voted answers are jokes or suggest solutions entirely unrelated to regexes and should be deleted, and many of the rest are entirely redundant. It would take a mod or a team of 20kers to clean that up. (Though I was wrong when I said there were 62 answers; I was including 22 deleted ones.)

Comment: OK, the question is now locked.