# Questions which seem non constructive

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, not-constructive

I am seeing several questions, some of which have been asked as recently as 6 months ago.

Some were closed as non constructive while some aren't.

What exactly is the criteria for this?

Comment: `"What exactly is the criteria for this"` - The criteria is, "if enough people see it".

Comment: Got some examples?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Not Constructive close reason explains why:

> As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A
> format. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or
> specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate,
> arguments, polling, or extended discussion.

What does that mean?  It means essentially that the question cannot be answered definitively; that there are many possible answers, all equally valid.  That's why [shopping questions](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) and [Gorilla Vs. Shark](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/) questions are Not Constructive.

However, occasionally someone asks a question in these categories that is *specific enough to be definitively answerable.*  Sometimes, these questions get a pass.

In addition, some close-worthy questions are so uninteresting that they never achieve the necessary views to obtain the requisite close votes.  Cast a moderator flag on those questions, and a moderator will evaluate them for closure.

**See Also** 
[What is a historical lock, and what is it used for?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for) 
[Real questions have answers](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/)