# Question with 4 reopen votes and 4 delete votes

Tags: discussion, specific-question, vote-to-delete, vote-to-reopen

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16142/what-do-branch-tag-and-trunk-really-mean) seemingly popular question has 4 reopen votes and 4 delete votes.

But it was closed by a moderator (Will) as not constructive. As I see the question, it's not really subjective (it is answerable), and also has some good answers. So I thought to take it to meta to find out what others think of it.

Should it be reopened, or should it be gone 'forever'?

Comment: The next vote decides.  :-) Having 25 answers kind of hints that there isn't a single correct answer. And, BTW, it probably takes 10 delete votes because it's highly upvoted (and if that happens it can potentially be undeleted again).

Comment: It is currently reopened with 2 close votes lodged. The question doesn't need to be open to be useful, it just needs to remain undeleted.

Comment: I got to cast the re-closing vote on it :) I think the number of answers (and much of their content) makes it clear why the question is "not constructive".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it qualifies for the [historical lock](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126631/162704):

> **When is it appropriate to lock a question for historical reasons?**
>
> Questions can be historically locked when:
>
> - The post is Off-Topic or Not Constructive, and
> - The post is stellar, in spite of its off-topic nature, and
> - There are a large number of views, upvotes and inbound links on the post, and
> - The post is contentious; i.e. it has been closed and reopened at least once, or deleted and undeleted at least once

Right now the question:

- Has a few awesome answers (especially 1,2,4),
- Is clearly Not Constructive,
- <del>Is open and *may* confuse newer members that they can ask similar questions</del>,
- Has been viewed 118,238 times, clearly a popular one,
- Has been closed an re-opened at least once,
- Hasn't been active for a while (other than today's re-opening),
- Won't benefit from further answers,
- Came close to being deleted.

Let's lock it.

---

**update**

And now it's closed again. Locking seems even more appropriate now, let's not get into a close / re-open war. It's a question that generated some awesome answers, no need to delete it, but also no need to update it, keep voting on it or re-open it again (Is there *any* benefit to further answers?).

Comment: "Is clearly Not Constructive," What is "not constructive" about it? It's asking a specific question about how many, *many* projects build their SVN repositories. Considering that most SVN projects will arrange their directories this way, there is obviously a reason for it. Thus, the question is answerable. Someone clearly knows what they're doing, how they work, and what they're for. So... where is it not-constructive? It's not subjective in any way, it's not a poll, and it's not an invitation to a discussion.

Comment: It's really no different from asking, "Why do I see lots of Python member variable names with a leading underscore?"

Comment: @NicolBolas For one it's not obvious if it's asking about the concepts or about how svn implements them. Most of the answers use _slightly_ different interpretations of the terms, which I'm guessing is the primary reason there are so many of them (and I can't see if there are any deleted ones). Editing it now to make it more specific would invalidate a few of the answers, unfortunately, and I guess that's why  it was initially closed. It was closed _again_, and although we don't have to agree if it's NC or not, I think it's obvious that it's contentious.

Comment: You skimmed right over the most important one: "The post is stellar, in spite of its off-topic nature". It seems like for most people the qualifications for historical lock are "old with lots of upvotes"

Comment: @MichaelMrozek `It's a question that generated some awesome answers`

Comment: Just to note: HL not only prevents new answers, it also prevents edits to existing answers. It truly is meant for questions whose only value is as a record of the past, questions that would otherwise be *deleted!* It is **not** a way to mark a question as "done".

Comment: @Shog9 Hm, yes, that's why I mentioned that it `hasn't been active for a while`. I checked whether there was any recent activity on the question or any of its answers before suggesting locking...

Answer (score 7):

> As I see the question, it's not really subjective (it is answerable), and also has some good answers.

So vote to re-open it. Just because a moderator closed it doesn't mean you can't disagree - that's the whole point of the close/reopen **voting** system.

I gotta disagree with Yannis here, I don't see any reason why this should be closed much less locked - yes, it's a simple question that's answered in the official documentation and can be easily googled, but, uh, [if you do that](http://www.google.com/search?q=what+do+branch+and+tag+mean+in+svn) you'll see that the top two answers point to that question on Stack Overflow.

***Mission Accomplished.***

Comment: It's already open again... After having been re-opened and closed already today. Maybe it's time for a lock :-).

Comment: Being closed and re-opened a couple of times really isn't a big deal. That's... kinda how the system is supposed to work - no reason 5 people out of the thousands of Stack Overflow members should decide the fate of a single question. That question's been around for four years and never got a *single* close vote until today (apart from Will's). I don't really think it's all that controversial.