# Are "historical significance" questions always supposed to be closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, historical-lock, askubuntu

The Ask Ubuntu question, [What IDEs are available for Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48299/what-ides-are-available-for-ubuntu), has a ["historical significance" notice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for), but is *still open*. (It seems to be neither closed nor locked.)

All questions with the notice that I've seen on other sites are closed, which makes sense since these are not considered good questions. So I previously [flagged that question](https://askubuntu.com/users/flag-summary/64389) with the message *If "historical significance", shouldn't the post be closed?*, but the flag was declined with the message "a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it".

Are "historical significance" questions always supposed to get closed? Is there a reason why this question is kept open despite having the message?

(Asking here because the basic question isn't specific to Ask Ubuntu.)

Comment: What problems might occur if the question is locked for historical significance, but not closed?

Comment: Many "historical significance" questions don't reach this status before they are both closed and deleted. Can't see that this is a *requirement* though, if someone would notice the significance anyway.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I *don't* think it's locked. I am able to comment on it.

Comment: TIL [gedit can be used as an IDE](http://askubuntu.com/a/48314)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question you linked is *not really historically-locked.*  Someone just put a Historical banner on it.  It's a bit of an edge case (much like "The Definitive C++ Book List" question on SO), because locking it would prevent it from being updated.

A question that has been genuinely historically-locked cannot be voted or answered.  So closing it would be redundant.

I've flagged the question for moderator attention, so that they can either put a real historical lock on it, or remove the "historical lock" banner from the top.

Comment: Oddly, the "fake lock" notice was added by a diamond mod in the first place.

Comment: Yeah, they're trying to keep it open so it can be maintained, but discouraging others from posting similar questions.  I seem to remember a Ubuntu Meta post about this particular question.