# Questionable delete!

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

"Will" just deleted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789031/what-development-environment-for-php-mysql-would-you-suggest) about developer tools and as such falls into the accepted areas for questions on SO. The question was there since 2009 and has helped a few people since. I find it rather hypocritical when the guy who earned 202 upvotes with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/89278/11995), deletes the question *in question* but not the question he got his 202 upvotes with, which is exactly from the same toolchain category.

Comment: Don't worry, any posts that are +3 deleted now, and older than 60 days, will always reflect in your actual rep, despite the questions never being valid in the first place. Win-win-lose-lose-win.

Comment: I'm not worries about my rep! This is not about rep, this is about hypocritical behaviour. How dare someone with lousy answers as the one I mentioned delete work I've done with a flick of his index finger? Go over your own stuff first, mods, before you delete at random.

Comment: The other question is historically locked because it gets a lot of traffic and flat-out deleting it wouldn't be beneficial to the Internet. The question you're worrying about has gotten 389 views over 3 years; hardly worth preserving.

Comment: I don't believe Will would lose any rep if that question were to be deleted today, so I doubt a vested interest is what keeps him from deleting it.

Comment: It even seems that Will's answer was Community Wiki from the start, so there was never any rep earned in the first place.

Comment: I'm actually going to disagree with the apparent community consesus here. While I do not believe that deletion of your post was questionable (your question was a regular shopping question), I don't agree that the other question should stay around just because it is older and has lots of views. It's also just a regular shopping question and a historical lock does not seem to be the right action for it. I think the other question ought to be deleted too.

Comment: @Ben fair point, flagging the other question for deletion and pointing to this discussion. (Edit: ah, only I can't flag that one. Huh?)

Comment: I haven't gotten any rep from that answer--its a wiki.  If it were deleted I wouldn't pitch a fit.  Shopping questions aren't allowed anymore, and there is no reason to keep around ones with low visibility, @benlee.  The deleted question had a whopping **422** views over three years, whereas the other question has **228293**.

Comment: @BenLee That is far from community consensus; the other question can't be flagged or voted for deletion since it is locked. I don't think most people would argue for keeping it around.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The question was probably flagged,  Will♦ responded, and just deleted it. It's a totally "not constructive" question by modern standards, and only had net 11 upvotes and 370 views throughout the entire thread. The deletion was valid, although it was useful to some people.

You mention "hypocritical behaviour", but [the other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89275/best-c-ide-or-editor-for-windows) you mentioned has a [historical lock](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for). It's a little older, a little more viewed (227969 views), and just happened to get "gradfathered in" as a popular question. I don't believe even a moderator can delete it.

Comment: ok. the comparison of his answer and my answer still leaves a bitter taste and a notion that something is wrong in the system.

Comment: The voters are ultimately the ones who decide that. I don't feel it's really possible to compare his answer to yours, they're totally different. His was certainly funnier though...

Comment: well, even democracy has drawbacks... http://wulffmorgenthaler.com/img/strip/-WM_strip_DK_20120218.jpg

Comment: his was funnier, and funny answers are all gone, because that's not what SO is about, is it... all the comic questions, etc. are all long gone.

Comment: Hmm... I'm not coming up with much, but you can [enjoy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234075/what-is-your-best-programmer-joke?lq=1) [these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/84556/whats-your-favorite-programmer-cartoon) in the meantime.

Comment: Mods can delete _anything_. We just have to unlock it first. We have very _few_ undoable powers (namely the ones relating to merging stuff and the ones in which an email gets sent out)

Comment: @Manishearth can a mod delete his own account? ;-) (please don't try it just to prove a point!)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Oh right, there's some crappy restriction on dealing high-rep accounts. I _can_ however, delete low-rep mods (and low-rep me if I was one). I'm not sure what happens if I delete Community♦. IIRC some mods got yelled at for banning Community♦ a long time ago, I'd rather not try that :s. Too bad SE isn't open source; I'd have a bunch of SE instances on my laptop, and be playing god on each one :D (I did this with Wikipedia once while I was writing an extension)

Comment: @Manishearth cool, glad mods can't delete me then!! :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Oh, they can. We just need to bribe a comm team member. You'll see.. Soon enough... Bwahahahaha }:-)