# Is the definition of a not constructive question taken too strictly?

Tags: discussion, moderation, not-constructive

Today I went to google to look for information on F# and stumbled into this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170749/what-is-f-what-can-it-do-that-c-sharp-cant

This question is marked as not constructive. The first comment is a suggestion for the user to look on Google first, and the second comment is a reply by the author specifying that Google will eventually index this same question and it will have valuable answers from the programming community to guide the person searching (which is how I got to the question).

The accepted answer has 142 votes. Why isn't it considered constructive? It steered me in the right direction...

Comment: It's not that the definition is too strict. It is that the name is misleading - it should be more on the lines of "not suitable to the site". Close reason names and descriptions are being reworked.

Comment: If it's not suitable to the site, then why keep the question up and let people find it on search engines?

Comment: @amhed: *Many* old questions of that family have been deleted- that one has 1 delete vote (of 3 needed) right now. Whether to keep unsuited but popular questions around is a controversial issue, which led to the compromise of a [historical lock](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for) being placed on some. (Interestingly, that question *was* deleted for a few weeks last December, but was [undeleted January 4](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/2170749/revisions)).

Comment: @amhed: if you point out broken windows, we'll fix them. I've only got 40 close votes a day and only a few hours of time to use them.

Comment: @sixlettervariables means this kind of [Broken Windows](http://www.artima.com/intv/fixit.html)

Comment: @amhed You've said it yourself. There is something of value there. If you outright delete it, you destroy value. And what's more, you will see quite some community resistance. In absence of a better archiving solution for valuable, yet off-topic content, closure (but not deletion) is not all that bad a solution.

Comment: I think that question should be locked rather than deleted (there are already 2 delete vote on it). The question is not that great, but the answer is of value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not constructive for several reasons. Let's have a look at the two sub-questions.

> I wonder why .NET world need another programming language ?

That is a question which will invite opinions. And it's something we don't do. It's not constructive.

> Is there a problem that C# cant solve and F# can?

Even if you steer clear from opinions on that one, you end up with a list of features one language has, that the other hasn't. Equally not-constructive as a result.

Perhaps an interesting question overall and something you might wonder about. But ultimately not fit for Stack Overflow.