# Highly upvoted old questions would be closed immediately if asked today.

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, old-questions

I know it was asked many times here and the historical significance should be taken into account in dealing with those questions: some highly upvoted old questions would be closed immediately if asked today.

But still I'm not sure:

- At which age or upvotes question becomes historical significant enough not to vote to close?
- Should I even flag those questions if I'm not sure what to do? We have 118k close votes review queue today, so I guess I should vote to close only in most serious cases?

Comment: Would this answer your questions? http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/174948/158100

Comment: @rene partially: should I vote to close less if the review queue is out of control today?

Comment: From my point of view you shouldn't take into account if some queue is out of control when you decide to take an action/close a question. If a question doesn't fit the current rules for on-topic-ness/quality vote to close. That not enough members handle the CV queue (or show up for [the weekly close vote event](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers))  is another issue.

Comment: Is it OK that I've edited the title to more informative?

Comment: Yes, it's a litte bit more informative, but still lacks the point after *But still I'm not sure*. English is not my primary, so I couldn't figure out a better title.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> At which age or upvotes question becomes historical significant enough not to vote to close?

Never. If it's no longer an on-topic and good question for the site, vote to close it. That doesn't mean it needs to be deleted. It doesn't imply the OP is a terrible user who has no clue how to predict the future. All it says is "Such questions shouldn't be asked (any more)".

> Should I even flag those questions if I'm not sure what to do?

If you're not sure, no. Skip. There are plenty of other users who will have an idea what to do. Let them handle it.

> We have 118k close votes review queue today, so I guess I should vote to close only in most serious cases?

Not really, no. The size of the queue doesn't matter. If that needs a solution, that's an other matter altogether. Just vote/flag as you would normally do.