# What changed at Stack Overflow to cause many old questions to be closed as not constructive?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

Example: [What are the most useful Intellij IDEA keyboard shortcuts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294167/what-are-the-most-useful-intellij-idea-keyboard-shortcuts?rq=1)

This question was asked on 2008-11-16.  It was closed as "not constructive" on 2011-09-09.  To state the obvious: This question was open for more than 1000 days, then closed as not constructive.

What changed at Stack Overflow that caused a huge increase in the number of closed questions?

Comment: The community developed and moved on. Such list questions are by now considered "not constructive" and usually closed when brought to the attention of some users. It helps to signal that such questions are no longer appropriate for the site.

Comment: What changed is that there are now 1000s of new questions every day. That makes finding the old NC questions harder, and some of them stay open longer. Don't assume we are all omnipotent and that we knew of the existence of that question all along.

Comment: What changed was an influx of absolutely pointless questions. Which lead to stricter standards. And then some.

Comment: Community [meta-tag:review] [queue for close votes](http://stackoverflow.com/review/close "here") has made this impact, along with associated [meta-tag:reviewer-badge]s that have been introduced along with it

Comment: @gnat not sure about that, at least not for questions closed during 2011 - those were closed mainly by moderators in joint effort to clean the place up.

Comment: See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_September.

Comment: BTW, now that you've draw the attentions of meta to it there is a real chance it will be deleted unless it gets a historic lock.

Comment: The site develops. What was considered a good question in the beginning of the site, might no longer be.

Comment: The question you link to is closed as not constructive, not as off topic.

Comment: @Juhana: what is difference the question closed! not constructive? but the question has 342+ve, and thanks I updated my question also

Comment: @Akam Why do votes matter? It's not constructive, therefore it has been closed as such.

Comment: @Doorknob: I don't know why people votes?!!

Comment: Votes are more of an indication of popularity in some cases, rather than an indication of fit for the site. There are tons of questions users seem to like, but which are not (or no longer) appropriate.

Comment: Popularity! question are not like politicians, the quality and usefulness of them decides

Comment: Nope, the topicality decides. Whether it's popular or not does not matter… we don't want to draw traffic for the wrong reasons anyway.

Comment: @slhck: how you define the down-vote for this question? I just asked for clarification and better image, not provided any idea or suggestion :)

Comment: Keep in that a lot (if not the majority) of users don't even know what Stack Overflow is all about. They see a question they like, and upvote it accordingly. That it's not within some set of (to them) arbitrary guidelines is perhaps not something they care about. The angry responses to the closure of such questions are often fun to watch...

Comment: @Bart Exactly, I like your comment, but why the question allowed as open for three years?

Comment: 1) The site develops (as I've said) 2) we can't see all the questions.  In this case, the first reason is the likely culprit.

Comment: [Voting on Meta is different.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)

Comment: @gnat thanks, but even that one not answered

Comment: Can't answer that one any better than @Bart already did in a comment... If these old questions *weren't* closed, people would complain the reverse: "why are old questions exempt from the new guidelines?"

Comment: @CodyGray: this is not a reason to justify your idea, there should be a clear rule on this site to close these questions...

Comment: What is unclear about it @Akam? If it's not a good fit, it should be closed. If it doesn't happen, vote accordingly. What do you expect?

Comment: @slhck 'Voting on Meta is different' but without 125 I can't even to down-vote!

Comment: There *is* a clear rule: it's covered in the site FAQ. Polls and "big list" questions are off-topic.

Comment: Why are you so interested in finding rules? The difference between the two questions? That one was asked on May 30th, yours was asked on July 21st. It hasn't been viewed as many times as your question. The universe is random. Things happen. Remember that *people* vote on questions, not a machine.

Answer (score 8):

> What is the policy to close these questions?

If a question is off topic according to the current scope of the site, it should be closed, regardless of its age.

This also applies to any of the other rules that are set in place, e.g. about questions being too subjective, opinion-based, too broad, etc.

An old question might have just slipped through the cracks before, and acquired a huge number of views and votes, but that doesn't protect it against scope changes. There is no benefit from keeping old questions open just because of their age or popularity, since their presence alone encourages people to ask similar questions under the assumption that they are allowed.

Simply put, if we didn't close the old questions—or somehow told users, "[hey, this is a *bad* question, don't even try to ask anything like this"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for)—how would they know not to ask a similarly bad one? We just gave them a good example of how popular such a question could become, and minutes later they might find their own question being closed.

Comment: ok show me one example that you closed one question that previously was not in the scope, but when the scope updated the question closed!

Comment: I could show you plenty (but from SU, where I'm a mod): [Does an equivalent of Time Machine exist for Windows?](http://superuser.com/questions/7423/does-an-equivalent-of-time-machine-exist-for-windows), [What Tiling Window Manager for Windows do you recommend?](http://superuser.com/questions/10347/what-tiling-window-manager-for-windows-do-you-recommend), [Which duplicate files and folders finders exist for Windows?](http://superuser.com/questions/8223/which-duplicate-files-and-folders-finders-exist-for-windows), [Hex editors for Windows?](http://superuser.com/questions/14465/) et cetera.

Comment: But how the scope changed against them? before---after

Comment: Before, we would have had lots of questions asking for software recommendations. Those get (understandably so) immensely popular, since everybody can participate in such a poll. That change came over time though – people started closing these more aggressively than in the early days, also with moderator intervention. We've later changed our FAQ to explicitly disallow product recommendation questions to make the scope clearer.

Comment: I hope to see old FAQ and Rules and compare them with new ones to show the truth

Comment: Since you're asking for facts to show the truth, are you implying I'm lying? Anyway, here's [the Meta Super User post](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/3587/update-the-faq-to-disallow-any-product-recommendation-questions) that made us change the FAQ to explicitly disallow product recommendation questions. I can't speak for Stack Overflow though, sorry. (The idea is the same nonetheless.) Don't forget that not every scope change has to be hardwired in the FAQ of the site. It's all about how the community behaves.

Comment: sorry, I didn't meant that but where are old FAQ's or rules that allowed these questions at that time and now these rules changed

Comment: We don't keep an archive of old FAQ revisions, but you'll get the idea. This happens with every site—their rules grow organically and change over time. Not every rule has to be written down like the law.

Comment: another question: comments considered as answer?

Comment: ...what? What are you asking?

Comment: @Bart: what did you meant? I asked if comments are considered as answers? any ambiguity here?

Comment: No, comments are comments. Not answers....why?

Comment: @Bart: but the question that referenced in my question has just comments, is this true or each question should has one answer as answer at least?

Comment: @Akam you're right in a way. Questions closed as duplicates should always point to an answer. That's not the case here, so sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Akam There is no such requirement on Meta. This requirement (as far as I know) for a question to need an answer to be eligible as a dupe, is only so on the main site. As for your last comment, I have no clue what you're going for there....

Answer (score 4):

Questions like "MySQLi vs. PDO" are not considered good questions for Stack Overflow because, as the close reason says, they tend to solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion. You can see that in some of the deleted answers that say things like "I use PDO because I don't want to learn another interface", "I decided to stick with MySQLi", or, my personal favorite, "♥ PDO".  These are just people's responses to an opinion poll.

After cleaning up a few of the most uninformative answers, I placed a lock on the question for several reasons:

1. There is some good content in the answers that shouldn't be deleted.
2. It's 4 years old and has nearly 50,000 views.
3. The links in the "Related" sidebar show that it's a question that's asked frequently, and linked to heavily. Deleting the question would break a lot of links.

Comment: The question that referenced in my question (I mean duplicate reference) has no answer but just comments?

Answer (score 2):

If the community wants to close them, they will. As a moderator, I try to encourage action on newer questions that are being posed everyday that need attention, instead of these 5 year old questions that haven't had much, (if any) attention in recent times.

Focus on the questions that need help right now, not the ones that aren't actively hurting the site. When I see moderator flags on these old questions, I tend to decline them if someone is just asking us to close them. There are close queues that can handle that sort of work.

Comment: Note that with the recent changes you wouldn't see any closure flags anymore anyway unless they used a custom text.

Comment: What is the harm in closing them? They will still be around, but clearly signal that such questions are no longer a good fit. I assume there is no problem there? Involving a moderator is of course another thing.

Comment: @slhck That's correct, but some people like to give us custom flags that ask for closure. We tend to decline these because they're trying to circumvent the normal process. If it's something exceptional, let us know, but for everyday closing, there's no need to involve moderators.

Comment: @Bart If people want to vote to close; that's their business. I'm not going to tell others how to spend their time -- however, what Stack Overflow needs is engaged users to help fix today's questions, not yesterday's relics.

Comment: Sure @GeorgeStocker. But if I stumble upon them, I'll vote according to the current standards. I don't seek them out.