# My question was marked as a duplicate, but the referenced question only has comments

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, meta

Today I asked this question:
**https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189745/why-are-some-questions-closed-off-topic-or-not-constructive-years-after-they**

After I got 3 good answers and many comments, my question was closed as a duplicate of this one:

**[What changed at Stack Overflow to cause many old questions to be closed as not constructive?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182299/what-changed-at-stack-overflow-to-cause-many-old-questions-to-be-closed-as-not-c)**

But that question has no answers, just comments. Is this a valid closure?

Also, why did my question receive a score of -5 and the linked question got a score of +5, even both are similar and discussing the same subject? Is there any problem with my question?

(Note: I just want to get a better idea about Stack Overflow. That's why I'm asking for an explanation)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is valid. It is ultimately the same question. And there is no requirement on Meta for a duplicate to have answers. And keep in mind that the initial votes might have come in before your question had any answers.

As for the voting, I don't know. Perhaps some disagree with a perceived sentiment that such questions should not be closed. But that's pure guesswork on my behalf.

Comment: There's no requirement for a duplicate to have answers on Meta, but the dupe text is horribly misleading: "This question has been asked before and already has an answer". No, it does not.

Comment: @Yannis True. Sounds like a feature request, if there isn't already one...

Comment: I agree that both are similar, but why not posted your comment as answer? I think its better to each question to has accepted answer this helps reader to know the right direction

Comment: You're referring to my comment on that question? Then I didn't post that as an answer, because I don't think it's substantial enough to be one.

Comment: yes you right, I think currently precedence should be set to my question because its more popular than previous one (-6V, more comments,  and it has 3 answers and one accepted) :)

Comment: The flag for moderator attention and ask them to reverse the duplicates. Perhaps they'll do so.

Comment: @Yannis Yeah, *someone's* complained about that already: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189782/meta-duplicates-dont-require-an-answer-dont-suggest-there-is-one-when-thats

Comment: Who is that bastard @TimStone? I'll tell him to...ah....I see....