# Meta duplicates don't require an answer. Don't suggest there is one when that's not true

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions, meta

This request was sparked [by this particular question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189780/my-question-was-marked-as-a-duplicate-but-the-referenced-question-only-has-comm). The vote to close as a duplicate on meta, in contrast to the main site, does not require for the duplicate to have an answer. Yet, the closure message still says:

> This question has been asked before **and already has an answer**.

...even when this is not the case. Perhaps we should either only show this particular sentence if there is indeed an answer, or remove this altogether for meta.

<sub>Note: I fear this might be a duplicate request, but I was unable to find one. (Not even one without an answer :) )</sub>

Comment: Good to see that I contributed something useful :)

Comment: Often the best way to notice issues with the site is for people to run into them @Akam ;)

Comment: Also, duplicates by the same user [do not require an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165852/). The notice on them should not have the part "and already has an answer", either.

Comment: I think questions on META should has at least one clear answer in order to mark it as reference for another duplicate question. At this case no changes required to be made for `This question has been asked before and already has an answer`.

Comment: That has [already been discussed here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169388/why-can-we-still-vote-for-duplicates-with-no-accepted-or-upvoted-answers-on-meta/169389#169389) @Akam.

Comment: Isn't this (ironically) dupe of [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/179355/152859)?

Comment: Them is fighting words @ShaWizDowArd. And one is a feature-request where the other one is a bug? .... meh

Comment: @Bart hmm... still think it's close enough but it isn't very important. Let them both live! :D

Comment: This isn't limited to Meta. I just closed [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31887223/827263) as a duplicate of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31882187/827263). The first one has the same "and already has an answer" wording, even though the second one has no answers.

Comment: @KeithThompson It isn't limited to Meta, but don't hold your breath for an answer -- I found this because there's a whole set of other questions from other people asking the same thing, closed as dupes, leading back here, and, of course, none of them has an answer either.  Obviously the message from on high is "we do not care and don't bother asking again".  Oh well oh well.

Comment: @goldilocks there is actually official answer, but in a comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179355/duplicate-question-close-reason-says-already-has-an-answer-which-is-often-fal#comment542691_179355

Answer (score 1):

[This was (mostly) implemented in March 2016](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22898/exact-duplicate-doesnt-require-answer-but-claims-one-exists). When the target question is unanswered, a different notice from the one you quote is now shown:

> This question was marked as an exact duplicate of an existing question.

Note that [until May 2018](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290420/what-is-the-difference-between-exact-duplicate-and-just-duplicate), this suffered from a bug, in which it checked to see if the closed duplicate question had no answers, instead of the target, when deciding if this notice or the other one should be shown. However, it now properly checks the target question and changes the notice as appropriate.