# Avoid same answer rewriting after deletion

Tags: discussion, answers, down-votes, deleted-answers

I've just made a test few minutes ago, the scenario is the following:

There was a question with 7-8 answers (all of them were correct because the question was very easy), someone downvoted all of the answers and leaves no comment (I suppose it was the question author because his question was downvoted). This situation has bothered me since I think it is not very professional and also I've loose 2 rep points for a whim. So I tried to delete my answer and repost it as-was. The trick worked: I've my 2 points back and the answer has now 0 votes.

I think that this trick should be avoided in some ways, obviously it can't be a simple text-check between the 2 answers because it will be easilly bypassed, I think that a good way can be that: if you repost an answer after an answer deletion, the rep points don't turn back.

Comment: Do it often enough and you might be automatically banned from answering. Deleting negatively voted posts is going to harm you. I guess that's enough of a counter-measure.

Comment: Is this your suggestion or it is already so? Because deleting downvoted posts has also a badge and should not be discouraged (I think)

Comment: That's already the case. But you'd need to do that a significant number of times. As in, if somebody would really be abusing the system, as you suggest, they might get into trouble. But if you occasionally delete an answer that wasn't all that could, there's no problem.

Comment: if you suspect an act of serial downvoting than just flag for moderators attention. I wouldn't worry much about the -2 until the moderator had a look. Also I wouldnt delete my answer even if it did have 1 downvote because it's a long game - other people who come across my answer may upvote it to counter. Good answers deserve upvotes not a single liners where there are 8 same answers etc

Comment: @mehow Downvoting all answers to a question isn't serial downvoting. No need to flag for moderator attention really.

Comment: Out of curiosity I searched for your answer. I'm sorry to tell you, but it has already been downvoted again...(same with the others, except the accepted one).

Comment: eheh I see but it is not a problem, it was just a test

Comment: The feature proposed in the linked dupe makes much more sense in my opinion and have pretty much the same goal - preventing duplicate answers.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I didn't see it, yes it is pretty the same. BTW it has no answers

Comment: @trippino that's why we're here... as for no answers that's because it's still "pending", like 99% of the feature requests - no wrong in asking again with different wording but closing as dupe will maintain some order. (don't delete your question because of that :))

Comment: @trippino Yeah, that's [a bit of a Meta issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189782/meta-duplicates-dont-require-an-answer-dont-suggest-there-is-one-when-thats), where duplicates are not required to have answers.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd yes I totally agree with you to close the question as duplicate (I've flagged it). Bart no problem I understand

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I will not delete it, I've flagged it. I won't delete because I think that two titles for the same question can help while searching for contents (indeed I didn't find 'your' question)