# What's up with this reCAPTCHA?

Tags: support, bug, captcha

> "I'm a human being."
>   - Carl Sagan

---

I, a human, asked a question on Stack Overflow today. Actually, no, I didn't, because Stack Overflow decided I'm not a human. I'm perfectly okay with this, since I admit I can be a little robotic in the mornings.

Usually, CAPTCHAs are of little annoyance to me, a human, who can answer them quite simply, like any human might.

This CAPTCHA, however, is stubborn. I, a human, have encountered this sort of stubborn, buggy CAPTCHA before, on [codegolf](/questions/tagged/codegolf), and I just ended up giving up and not asking.

Today, though, I, a human, would really like to know why Python lists behave they do, and so I, a human, would like to ask my question.

Here's what went down: After clicking "Ask your question" I got redirected to the "Human Verification" page, at which point I was asked about street signs. I ticked the boxes (which seem to be in low-graphics / no-JavaScript mode*, perhaps my crappy Internet connection is to blame for that), and clicked "Verify". Then, I had to repeat this several more times on different sets of images.

Different from any CAPTCHA I've done before is this:

[image: Is that my hashed password in the URL bar?]

<sup>I'm assuming that's a unique token in the URL, which will grant access to my account. Have at it, while I go change my password and lock down my account.</sup>

As you can see, there's some text (my password hash??) which I copied into the box below. How great! I don't know how this will deter a bot, since JavaScript can read and write the clipboard, but fair enough.

....Now what? There's no button to click, the page didn't reload after 2 minutes like I, a human, expected it to. What do I do? Do I have to type a secret code?

I just want to ask my question on Stack Overflow :(

---

*The boxes don't look as modern and fancy as the "real" reCAPTCHA I'm used to from Google, and they don't behave in quite the same way.

Comment: Did you try with a different browser, e.g. Chrome?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I don't have Chrome or another browser on this PC yet, it's gonna take a year to download on this slow internet :(

Comment: Well, something on your end is borked, otherwise we would have been flooded with such bug reports. Anyhow, you might get more attention and faster response in [MSO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/) since this appear to happen only on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @ShadowWizard it's happened to me before on http://codegolf.stackexchange.com, which is why I ask here and not MSO. Moreover, I was using Chrome when it happened on [tag:codegolf] but I didn't bother report it.

Comment: I see. Anyway, turns out it was already reported - my guess is borked connection leading to missing JS files, and IP changing rapidly leading to  you being identified as a bot. Being just wild guesses, I don't think I can post them as answers, and hopefully a dev will have a look at some point.

Comment: How can this be a dupe of a question with no answer? That one is completely unhelpful.

Comment: @ShadowWizard okay, fair enough I suppose.

Comment: Yeah, here on MSE bugs are closed as duplicate even if it's still not solved. Feel your pain, but really nothing I can do.

Comment: @cat So that if anyone has an answer, they only need to answer 1 question. Theoretically.

Comment: @ShadowWizard isn't the message on the closure, simply a lie? *This question has been asked before and* **already has an answer**  *If those answers do not fully address your question, please ask a new question.* There are no answers on the older question, so how does that help the OP? Why hasn't the SE team posted an explanation?

Comment: @Mari-LouA it is a bug in the app. The site shows a different message.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Now I have Chrome; the site, too says "This question has been asked before and already has an answer."

Comment: @cat oh you mean the message below the question, not on top. Right, and I am sure there is a bug report/feature request already for that, will take a look.

Comment: Found it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189782/meta-duplicates-dont-require-an-answer-dont-suggest-there-is-one-when-thats