# I can no longer accept answers for my question as I don't work in that project

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions, accepted-answer

There are a few questions I've asked which took much longer time to get a proper solution. But I can no longer use/test those solutions due to different reasons. So those questions remain unsolved.
Is it possible for the ***community to take over those questions*** so that if any one encountering the same issue can test the suggested solutions and accept the working solution.

Comment: I wanted to ask about transferring questions to community or some other user.

Comment: @gnat Sort of, but given there is nothing useful written there... maybe wait to see if the new question gets an answer, and then close in the opposite direction?

Comment: @Behaviour http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189780/my-question-was-marked-as-a-duplicate-but-the-referenced-question-only-has-comm

Comment: @gnat Bart's answer does not convince me that such closing is desirable. Anyway,  It seems this question is a feature request, while the suggested duplicate is not.

Comment: @Behaviour as a feature request, it was asked and answered ([meta-tag:status-declined]) in [Would it be possible to have a “community accepted” feature?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3669/165773)

Comment: I'm with you on this. I wish the SO team would listen.