# Handling of highly-voted popular off-topic questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, off-topic

Could there be a permanent, read-only migration destination for those highly voted, popular "dinosaurs", which are permanent delete candidates or are dangling between `on hold` and `reopen`?

Something like museum.stackexchange.com (museum could be called offtopics, cellar, oldies whatever).

Comment: Would this be more appropriate as a question or proposal on http://area51.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: @CodyGray sorry did not find this thread, since my focus was not on deleted.

Comment: Fair enough. This has just been discussed fairly extensively on Meta. We now have a better solution, though, and that is [a historical lock](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for). (Creating a Stack Exchange site that people by definition cannot interact with doesn't exactly work well.)

Comment: @CodyGray thanks for above link, so this a pure moderator action?

Comment: @bummi if you mean adding a historical lock to a post, yes it is.  I'm  pretty sure that only diamond moderators can do it, and it is not part of the tools given to 10K/20K users.

Comment: Yes, it is diamond moderator only. Not all old content is of such high quality that it needs to be kept around. If you think a question merits a historical lock, you can either flag for moderator attention and request it, or ask a [discussion] question on Meta featuring a link to the question. Lots of people have done that in the past for specific questions; you can turn some of them up with a search here.

Comment: @CodyGray Thanks, seems as if I did not use the suitable keywords on my search :-(