# Questions doesn't show up in searching by individual tags

Tags: discussion, support, tags, search

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550632/favorite-django-tips-features) with 300+ upvotes (Sep'13) has tags `python`, `django` etc. When I search for the tag `[django]` and order by `votes`, I don't see it listed. By vote count, it should be at the second number. What am I doing wrong?

**Update**: There are several such posts with high votes that are locked/closed because they don't strictly adhere to SO guidelines. Despite that, they offer tremendous value as shown by the number of votes / favorites.

If they are taken off the search results or one has to tweak the search query for them to show up, I think many newcomers will be missing out on knowledgeable posts.

---

[image: Search Results]

Comment: I think it's because the question is locked. Locked question does not shows up in a search.

Comment: If you want to find it you could search with this `[python] [django] is:question`. (I've still have some difficulties with the search function on SO)

Comment: @Oded You've removed the tag 'bug'. Isn't this a bug? I'd want to see that question listed by votes. Judging by the number of votes/favorites, it adds considerable value even though it trips over some of the SO guidelines. If I search [django] tips or [django] <some word from that question> it shows up in the results. But with [django] alone, it doesn't

Comment: The [meta-tag:bug] should be reserved for actual bugs in the software - not policy/design issues.

Comment: Why do you say it's a policy design issue? I was editing the comment as you answered to show that [django] alone doesn't bring it up in the results buy appending a related word shows it in the results.

Comment: @buffer it's not a bug.  It shows up in search results in both cases (it's the 5th down when searching only the 1 tag), and is excluded from question lists intentionally - as all historical lock questions are.

Comment: @NickCraver Please post a screenshot or url where you can see it in search results with 1 tag. I can't

Comment: @buffer [here you go](http://i.stack.imgur.com/MQsvq.png). Tag page [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) is **not** search results and considered what Nick called "question lists", hence historically locked questions won't appear there regardless of their score.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I think you haven't followed the comment trail. I know it can show up with 1 tag with relevant words appended (I've mentioned that twice already). I'm curious to see it show up with 1 tag only & nothing else. That seems like a bug to me.

Comment: @buffer see my comment edit.

Comment: @buffer tags *only* redirects to `/questions/tagged`, intentionally as a shortcut...where historical lock questions are intentionally not shown.  We show them in the search result page only, even your comment about `[django] is:question` not working is incorrect...it's the 5th result.

Comment: I see. I'll remove that comment. Search page redirecting to 'tagged' is a bit counter-intuitive to me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a historical lock, and what is it used for?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for) - specifically, "*on main (non-meta) sites, historically locked questions are omitted from normal question lists (those on the home page, /questions, and the various per-tag lists), but can still be found by searching for words in the post or title*"