# Why is it that a question that was put on hold once then reopened can be put on hold again by only 5 mods?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20149741/why-is-the-given-name-fred-disproportionately-used-to-name-variables-or-classe) on SO. It was put on hold for being "opinion-based", which it was really not since it reopened later as it was deemed "historical and not opinion-based". Now 5 mods have decided to put it on hold *again* for being opinion-based, *again*.

I think that this situation is unfair for two reasons : 
1. Why is it that the 5 mods quorum doesn't grow each time? Am I going to have to petition to reopen it everyday?
2. I can't vote to reopen it again, since i voted last time. So I can't signal my intention to have it reopened.

Comment: Any user with >3k rep can vote to close/reopen, not just mods. It sounds like your question is right on the border of off topic; I suggest editing it to resolve any issues people have highlighted

Comment: Although reading the question it kindof is primarily opinion based;  why a small group of people use a particular example name is unknowable unless you actually ask the people in question, and each wikk probably have a different reason

Comment: That question should have never been reopened.  It is the quintessential example of a ["what color should I paint the bikeshed"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parkinson's_law_of_triviality) question.

Comment: @RobertHarvey. No, it is the quintessential example of "why is it that a majority of people paint the bikeshed green?" which has an answer which is that it blends better with the rest of the garden.

Comment: Ask yourself this: will the answer to the question (whatever it is) make you a better programmer?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Certainly it would make me a more knowledgable one. The venerable IETF released a whole RFC on the etymology of foo [http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3092.txt]. I think they did it because some people wonder and that makes it a legitimate question.

Comment: Also, ignoring the whole opinion based thing: I'm not sure the history of programming is on topic either unless it impacts actual programming

Comment: Frankly, programers from my generation use Foo as the first meta-syntactic name. "Fred" is some new fangled silliness.

Comment: [Foo is already covered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4868904/what-is-the-origin-of-foo-and-bar) here.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Holy hell I did not know that. So origin of foo is fair and origin of fred is not. Yeah, right.

Comment: Well, how deep does this well go?  If I asked "Why Fred and not Sally" would that be on-topic?  If I asked why it was an Anglo-Saxon name, and not a German name, would that be on-topic?  Foo has some precedence in the annals of programming history; Fred does not.

Comment: @gurg note that the scope of the site has changed; historic content should not be used to justify new content

Comment: @RobertHarvey Because Sally is not used! (or at least not disproportionately!)

Comment: @RichardTingle Ok, that'd be a fair answer and I would accept it, had it said this in the first place.

Comment: @Gurg I have never heard Fred used.

Comment: @RichardTingle: I used it a long time ago before I discovered Foo and Bar, because it's easy to type on a keyboard.  When I wrote sorting algorithms, I had some well-placed names that I always used: Aaron Aames, Fred Fels, Malcolm Middle, Zamon Zorr.  Fred Fels was the name of one of my school counselors.  Now there's some significant computing history for ya.

Comment: @RobertHarvey,RichardTingleOr maybe it has precedence and you did not know it. Guess what, there are examples in the question and someone answered it citing another source, but sure, you two have never heard it so that doesn't exist.

Comment: This might be a more substantial and weighty issue if ten people hadn't agreed that it was off-topic.  Good, on-topic questions never get a single close vote.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Argument of authority.

Comment: Maybe so.  But that's how we work here, by community consensus.

Comment: None of the users who voted to close your question were mods.

Comment: This question was recently asked; [where-should-i-ask-about-the-history-of-programming](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208815/where-should-i-ask-about-the-history-of-programming) which covers this very well

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can rage against the machine (pointless, and overrated imho), or you can understand the reasoning behind this.

I'll point you to a couple specifics behind the ethos of StackOverflow that can be gleaned from the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help):

> This site is all about getting answers. It's not a discussion forum. There's no chit-chat.

Trivia questions, while fun (I love trivia, play a lot of [Buzztime](https://www.buzztime.com/) when I get the opportunity), are definitely chit-chatty.  Why someone would use `fred` as a variable name is pretty much useless information that won't help you become a better programmer or solve any issue you are currently facing.  Speaking of which...

> Focus on questions about an actual problem you have faced. Include details about what you have tried and exactly what you are trying to do.

Where's the actual problem you are facing here?  Is not knowing the reasoning behind a throwaway variable name a problem?  No, performant thread synchronization in collection access is a software problem.  This, again, is trivia.

I agree with you that the [foo question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4868904/what-is-the-origin-of-foo-and-bar) is a similar example.  It should be closed (voted for that) or given a [historical lock](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for).  It *isn't* an example of how you are right, but of how "StackOverflow is not a perfect example of itself".  You will always find counterexamples for pretty much every rule here, just because SO isn't perfect due to the number of human beings administrating and participating within it.

Answer (score 14):

First of all, don't editorialize in the question itself to explain why it should be opened or not.  Improve the question in the body of the question, argue your case in comments and on Meta.

Second, ten people have now voted to close that question and five have voted to reopen.  It seems pretty fair to me that the question should be closed.

Comment: With your reasonning, when 105 persons have voted to close and 100 to reopen, then it is fair to close which i do not agree with.

Comment: Not exactly.  Ten over five is a two to one ratio.

Comment: @GurgHackpof Why not? Why should reopen votes count more than close votes? (More than they already do. It *always* takes more close votes than reopen votes to keep a question closed.)

Comment: @Gurg A question would never get to that point, though. It would have been brought up on Meta and heavily discussed. Most questions would never make it past a third close/reopen cycle without moderator intervention.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Well, one reason for not being one-to-one is that you cannot reopen a question that was not closed beforehand. So maybe the 5 guys that actively voted for the question would have reopened it too, had they had the chance to do so... (or maybe they are the same 5 guys) Another reason is that the fact that it was reopened shows that it is in fact a close call so raising the quorum makes sense to me.

Comment: @Gurg assuming that there is no edit in between; if people would just vote either way to flip the questions state then something is seriously wrong.

Comment: @RichardTingle There were no other edits than arguing the case which I have since learned I should not do.

Comment: @Gurg In which case no one in their right mind would vote both ways