# Why was this Question Regarding GCC and Clang on Linux Deleted?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, closed-questions

This question was a genuine inquiry for me when I was studying programming in C and considering switching to Clang which appeared to me more user friendly and more newbie friendly than GCC. I did in fact switch to Clang, since then based on the answers I received.

[Clang vs GCC for my Linux Development project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205858/clang-vs-gcc-for-my-linux-development-project)

I suspect that the linked page is now only visible to users with very high reputation and moderators. I still think the info provided is very useful to anybody starting with C programming and was dismayed at it's closing and really surprised by it's deletion. The very positive upvotes the question and the answers provided (65 upvotes for the question and 48 upvotes for the accepted answer, 18 for the second answer etc. for those that can't see the question ...) should give a hint that people found it useful. Even if some people think it is not a perfect fit within Stackoverflow (I still disagree even with that) why not just leave it closed but not delete it.

Addendum: Thanks to jmort253, the question has been edited to reflect the issue I was having during my C programming course. I am willing to edit the question further, but while I can see the question, I am unable to edit it myself (the edit button is still greyed out), in an effort to have the question undeleted (and hopefully later re-opening it).

Comment: As a general rule, "compare and contrast" questions don't go down well these days.

Comment: I cast the last undelete vote, it now is visible to all users. I suggest we put a historical lock on it, or keep it around as an "FAQ"-type question.

Answer (score 6):

The question asks for advantages and disadvantages. Such questions are not a good fit for Stack Overflow:

> As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion. If you feel that this question can be improved and possibly reopened, visit the help center for guidance.

The problem with these questions is they're not about a real, actual problem you're facing but are instead hypothetical, theoretical, and answers will be based on speculation. Every programming issue is different, and there may very well be cases where one is better than the other...

But we don't know that unless you're crystal clear on what your problem is. When you include enough detail about your problem in your question, those with experience in both compilers will be able to more clearly tell which one is best for *your* unique problem.

This has the nice added benefit of more targeted, shorter, concise answers, and makes it more likely that someone searching for the same problem will find an answer that also solves their problem.

This question has been closed for a long time. Closed questions that don't get edited and improved typically get removed. You might still be able to edit it, or convince a moderator to undelete it so you can edit it, but if you're not going to improve it, it's probably best to leave it deleted. Hope this helps.

Comment: So help me edit it and undelete it. As someone taking a College course in C programming at the time and hearing about Clang for the first time (I was using GCC 4.6 at the time), the apparent user-friendliness of Clang appealed to me and I was checking if there any downsides or gotchas about using it. Seems like a genuine problem or questin to me.

Comment: @haziz - I threw in an undelete vote and made an edit to remove some of the "trigger words" that make folks want to cast close votes. I can't promise anything, but hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. Now just waiting for one more undelete vote!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the rules on this community have changed a lot in the last year.

Before there was more tolerance for broad and opinionable question. Now it's enough to use some "trigger words" and folks want to close or delete questions.

I found this old blog article https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/

It was saying:

- "We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed."
- "We never claimed that subjective questions were horrible abominations that should never be asked."
- "Because we believe so deeply in learning, we are willing to go to great lengths to suppress the discussion, debate, and opinions that — while plenty entertaining — cause most forums to inevitably break down."
- "They talk about how “opinion, by itself, is noise.” They’re not saying that subjective opinions are to be avoided; they’re attempting to mold and shape their inherently subjective Q&A into something constructive, informative and helpful. "

3 years ago SE was not so strict agains opinionable questions.

Comment: It is true, not necessarily a bad thing though.  We've learned what works and what doesn't.  If yours is an exemplary example of something which usually doesn't work but in this case did you could request a historical lock on it (I can't see it so I can't comment on if it is eligable). Assuming of course your edits don't make it on topic today

Comment: Interesting.. how do you ask for it?

Comment: you flag it under "other". A historical lock prevents new answers or edits **but** keeps it around for everyone to view forever

Comment: This explains historical locks in more detail: [What is a historical lock, and what is it used for?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for)

Comment: Historical locks are possible, but they're generally used very sparingly, so I would approach this humbly, just in case. Like community wiki, locks are not a "quick fix" for questions that don't fit the format.