# Is it acceptable to bend the question guidelines for a popular question?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, close-reasons, scope, guidelines

I am trying to get this question re-opened: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/141039/what-are-the-biggest-unsolved-problems-in-reinforcement-learning?noredirect=1#comment269588_141039

The user who closed it refuses to accept my analogy with this question:
[What are the 'big problems' in statistics?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2379/what-are-the-big-problems-in-statistics)

On the basis that that question is popular. (Other reasons have been given, e.g., that the 2nd question is more specific, but that is not true.)

**So, my question is**: is the popularity of a question that admittedly does not follow the guidelines a sufficient reason to keep the question open?

P.S. To be clear, I don't think *either* question should be closed.

Comment: The moderator you are debating here is making a judgment call based on their years of interaction with the site. That decision is *informed by* guidelines, it does not *bend* them. Their experience provides them a great deal of perspective. If anything, as whuber points out, your analogy should cause the *other* thread to be closed (actually, there is [an even better tool designed for this exact scenario](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126587/254929)), not yours to be reopened.

Comment: No, my analogy only implies that the threads should receive the same treatment.

Answer (score 11):

> is the popularity of a question that admittedly does not follow the guidelines a sufficient reason to keep the question open?

No.

In fact, several of the close reasons exist precisely *because* questions meeting those criteria are so popular.  Particularly very subjective questions (but also often very broad questions, your examples are a mix of both), tend to be *very* popular.

Everybody *loves* to share their own opinions and to argue with each other until the end of time about which OS is better, whether we should be using tabs or spaces, or what color we should paint the bike-shed.  These types of questions are considered of scope for the site because they're not helpful (and also because they don't fit well with the model of SE) *even though they are so popular*.

Comment: “of scope” I'm a little confused. Did you mean “out of scope”?

Comment: @alex yes. Edited.