# How many network sites have their top question hidden?

Tags: discussion, historical-lock

Looking at the highest voted questions on various StackExchange sites is something we all like to do.

For instance, if you look at ServerFault, you can see the top question has 469 votes (as of this writing):

[image: ServerFault highest voted questions]

However, if you're a super-cool person in the secret club, you know that there is another question with almost three times as many votes:

[Our security auditor is an idiot. How do I give him the information he wants?](https://serverfault.com/questions/293217/our-security-auditor-is-an-idiot-how-do-i-give-him-the-information-he-wants)

[image: ServerFault top question]

How many StackExchange sites have their top question hidden from the highest voted questions tab?

(Of course, ServerFault might have an even higher voted question, for even cooler people in an even more secret club.)

Comment: You mean how many have shame they're trying to sweep under a clear plastic rug?

Comment: That one is the highest-voted existing question on SF: http://serverfault.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aq  A similar search query will bring up results for other sites.

Comment: I think that the questions can only be shown the the top voted questions only if it is not locked.

Comment: This is the result of [historical lock](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for): "Historically-locked questions are omitted from normal question lists (those on the home page, /questions, and the various per-tag lists)" /cc @PythonMaster

Comment: +1 for showing me the funniest question ever! :)

Comment: Sadly, that's an entirely crappy question that was not put down quickly enough and the rest is history.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As I understand it you're asking if the question with the top score is locked on each site. Here's the results for the [top 11 sites sorted by number of questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/):

- Stack Overflow: [Top Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array) (11.7k score) is not locked.
- Mathematics: [Top Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71874/can-i-use-my-powers-for-good) (0.9k score) is locked.
- Super User: [Top Question](https://superuser.com/questions/792607/why-does-windows-think-that-my-wireless-keyboard-is-a-toaster) (1.5k score) is not locked.
- Server Fault: [Top Question](https://serverfault.com/questions/293217/our-security-auditor-is-an-idiot-how-do-i-give-him-the-information-he-wants) (1.3k score) is locked, but [Question with Second Highest Score](https://serverfault.com/questions/9708/what-is-a-pem-file-and-how-does-it-differ-from-other-openssl-generated-key-file) (0.5k score) is not locked.
- Ask Ubuntu: [Top Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30334/what-application-indicators-are-available) (0.6k score) is not locked.
- TeX - LaTeX: [Top Question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94889/how-can-i-explain-the-meaning-of-latex-to-my-grandma) (0.5k score) is not locked.
- Meta Stack Exchange: [Top Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) (1.5k score) is not locked.
- Unix and Linux: [Top Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34196/why-was-chosen-to-represent-the-home-directory) (0.6k score) is not locked.
- Stack Overflow на русском: [Top Question](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1811/hello-world-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B9-main) (0.1k score) does not appear to be locked.
- Math Overflow: [Top Question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23478/examples-of-common-false-beliefs-in-mathematics) (0.5k score) is not locked.
- Cross Validated: [Top Question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2691/making-sense-of-principal-component-analysis-eigenvectors-eigenvalues) (0.3k score) is not locked.

It seems that Server Fault is an outlier among the sites with the largest number of questions, since only one of the other sites' top questions (by score) is locked.