# What to do when I want to improve a locked post?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, locked, historical-lock

The locked and closed question [Hidden features of Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python) has an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/101892/1587329) that contains an anti-pattern, [a backslash to continue a line](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/doanddont.html#using-backslash-to-continue-statements).

I tried to edit and to comment, which both did not work, as this is a [historically locked question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for). Yet, it would be nice if it could avoid advertising anti-patterns.

Is there any way to amend the answer, or any alternative?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For some cases, a moderator might unlock and relock a post, however, I don't think that should be the case for this post and this type of edit.

From the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for) you reference (emphasis mine):

> Historically locking a post ends the debate over whether a question should be kept on the site or deleted, and **is often the final state of a question** that has been deleted and undeleted more than once.

So that is it. A locked post is locked, and will probably always remain what way (note that actively maintained posts shouldn't be locked, so this one wasn't maintained at least for some time). These posts will not be maintained any more, no matter how good your edit might have been.