# Are historically locked questions supposed to show up on the "highest voted questions" list?

Tags: bug, historical-lock

I might be missing something, but my understanding is that this

> Historically-locked questions are omitted from normal question lists (those on the home page, /questions, and the various per-tag lists), but can still be found by searching for words in the post or title (via either site-search or Google, etc). ([What is a historical lock, and what is it used for?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for))

means that [Is it "bear" or "bare" with me?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1269/is-it-bear-or-bare-with-me) and [What does a single letter "J" mean in emailing?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46829/what-does-a-single-letter-j-mean-in-emailing) should not show up on https://english.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes, yet I can clearly see them there.

Comment: Yep, looks like a regression.