# When historical-locked questions are bumped, the site front page has fewer questions for logged-in users

Tags: bug, homepage, historical-lock

[Because of reasons](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3994/), I've been editing a bunch of historical-locked questions on Anime.SE recently (I have a diamond there). At first, I thought I'd have to do them in small batches so that they wouldn't clog up the site front page. Much to my surprise, historical-locked questions don't show up on the front page, even when bumped by a mod edit. Awesome!

Then I figured, hey, let me edit a bunch of them at once rather than breaking them up into small batches. So I edited about 35 of them in the past 20 minutes... and this happened:

[image: front page of Anime.SE right now]

The "active" tab of our front page is now down to seven questions! Oops...

Note, however, that for non-logged-in users, the front page is still the full 14 questions that it always is. And the "hot" tab still has its regular allotment of questions for all users as well.

Comment: i was going to ping JNat and our mods in the chat room to confirm if closed questions generally don't show up for logged out users but when i reloaded the page (rather than pressing the "5 new questions" banner) they all disappeared

Comment: Might or might not be related, but historically-locked questions also [aren't hidden from normal question lists](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/287789) the way I understand they're supposed to be.

Comment: it appears it doesn't affect the `/questions` page (eg. http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=active)

Comment: Looks like the hiding is performed **after** questions are loaded, that's the bug.