# Locked questions are bumped to the front page on mobile web but not on desktop

Tags: bug, mobile-web, locked-questions, homepage

As implied in [When historical-locked questions are bumped, the site front page has fewer questions for logged-in users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291375/261498), the desktop version of the front page does not show locked questions even when they are edited. However, I've discovered that on the mobile version of the site, these locked questions can be bumped to the front page.

[image: screenshot of mobile front page]

These are all locked questions that had their tag edited per [a decision](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3994/2604) on the meta of Anime.SE; [here's](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/24529/2604) a link to one of those listed in my screenshot. Is this discrepancy a bug?