# Which posts are shown in the 'Locked Posts' widget in the ♦ moderator tools?

Tags: support, moderator-tools, locked

One of the tools ♦ moderators have at their disposal is a list of locked posts. It's available at the relative URL `/admin/posts/` on their website. Not all locked posts on the site are shown here, what are the criteria for posts to be included here? Is there a search query available to all users which produces the same results?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Experimental research suggests the following posts are included (as long as they're not deleted, like e.g. spam posts):

- Locked questions which

  - are not closed
  - have not been merged
- All locked answers

Historical locks are [sometimes treated differently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126631/295232) than other lock types, but not here.

It's not possible to filter for non-merged questions, but otherwise the list is a combination of the search queries `locked:yes closed:no` and `locked:yes is:answer`. It is sorted by the date the lock was set, newest first (visible in the first column of the screenshot).

Comment: This accurately reflects the logic used to render that list. The only other criteria is that the post cannot be deleted (which probably seems obvious, but is worth noting for a moderator tool).

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Sorry, but the 'cannot be deleted' is not obvious to me: when would moderators be unable to delete a post?

Comment: I think @Shog9's point is that the list doesn't show any deleted posts, even if they were locked before deletion. (to get those, you can search for `locked:yes deleted:yes`)

Comment: @Nathaniel ah, of course, thanks!