# Showing a "vote both the question and the answers up" banner on a locked question

Tags: bug, voting, locked-questions

The banner shown encouraging upvoting is redundant when the question is locked, as locking prevents voting on <s>any of the answers or</s> the question. (Answers can still be voted on, as pointed out in [Glorfindel's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/330857/258647).)

Should the banner be omitted for questions that cannot be voted on?

Example image:

[image]

Comment: But the answers aren't locked in this case ...

Answer (score 2):

It shouldn't be omitted in this particular case, since it's still possible to vote on the *answers* - you can try it out yourself. There are so-called [historical locks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126587/295232) which completely lock down voting on all posts, for which not showing the banner would make sense. (Maybe it already happens there?)

I do agree that it would be nice to change it to something like

> Welcome back! If you found some of the answers useful, don't forget to vote them up.

(Another blemish of the current wording is that it seems to encourage voting up bad answers.)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this - it was historical locks I was mixing this up with.