# Historically-locked questions aren't merely "currently" not accepting new answers or interactions

Tags: feature-request, locked-questions, post-notices, historical-lock

Most manual locks applied to posts, such as content dispute or comment-only locks, are meant to just be temporary, and lifted at an appropriate time. As such, the part of the post notice that says "it is not currently accepting new [answers or] interactions" makes sense.

However, *historical* locks on questions are meant to be *permanent*. Generally, historical locks are *not* lifted intentionally unless the lock is determined to be in error. Per the [historical lock FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for):

> A historical lock is a mechanism by which moderators can mark posts as **historical artifacts**. [...] [It] is often the **final** state of a question that has been deleted and undeleted more than once, or subject to a close or delete war.

The post notice for historical locks, though, says this:

> This question and its answers are locked because the question is off-topic but has historical significance. It is **not currently** accepting new answers or interactions.

This part of the notice implies that new answers or interactions may potentially be accepted in the future. This is usually true for posts locked as content disputes or other "temporary" lock reasons, but is usually *not* true for questions locked as historical significance. Therefore, for historical locks, the notice should instead read:

> This question and its answers are locked because the question is off-topic but has historical significance. It is **no longer** accepting new answers or interactions.

This modification to the notice doesn't give mistaken indication or false hope that the question will eventually be open to interactions.

Looking at the [help center page on locks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/locked-posts), the "wiki answer" lock reason is also listed as a "permanent" lock reason. A similar thing should also be done for that lock reason.