# Cannot follow locked posts; wrong error message when attempting to do so

Tags: bug, error-message, locked-questions, locked, follow-post

I just visited the question here, which is locked as a "community effort":

[What is a historical lock, and what is it used for?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for)

I (legitimately) wanted to "Follow" the question so that I would be notified if the status of those types of questions changed in the future.

When I press the "Follow" button, it appears to work. But then I notice a banner at the top of the page:

> This post has been locked; locked posts can't be voted on

[image: This post has been locked; locked posts can't be voted on]

When I refresh the page, it's clear that the "Follow" action did not work.

Something's clearly wrong here. Ideally I would be able to follow the question. If not, the action button should not be available. And if I can click the button, it should show the correct error message.

Comment: What would be the point of following a question that can never change? Just bookmark it. Alternatively follow the answer (the bit that can change).

Comment: @RobertLongson the actual bug is the wording of the error message, IMO. Should be at least "locked posts can't be followed".

Comment: The same error happens when trying to *un*follow a locked post (if you followed it before it was locked). I bet it's the same bug in the backend, probably not worth reporting separately.