# This post has been locked; locked posts can't be voted on

Tags: bug, locked, follow-post

Now that we can unfollow deleted posts, there is an issue with being unable to unfollow answers which were locked due to being rude or spam.

There is a button on the answer and when clicked it changes state, but I get a red popup with the message:

> This post has been locked; locked posts can't be voted on

Also, the unfollow/following button on the questions is gone, I can only unfollow it by going through the profile.

If the answer was deleted by the owner then I can both unfollow and follow it again without issues.

I haven't tried it with locked questions yet, but I can't even follow a deleted question again from my profile page. I get this error message:

> Following not enabled for this post.

To summarize:

- I can unfollow deleted questions, but only from profile page
- I can't follow deleted questions
- I can unfollow and follow deleted answers. Both from post view and profile
- I can't follow/unfollow locked posts

P.S. Filtering doesn't work with paging. When I select answers only and go to second page the filtering turns off.

Comment: It's a duplicate. https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/349629/515960 for the most part

Comment: And this one too https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348413/515960