# How do I unfollow a migrated question?

Tags: bug, migrated-questions, merged-questions, follow-post

I followed [this question at CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/474169/is-a-decreasing-and-assymptotic-for-y-const-convex-function-always-logarithmic), which was subsequently [migrated to Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3740074/51074).

I am now seeing the CV question in my "Following" tab on my profile, with an "unfollow" link.

If I click that link, a popup informs me that "This post has been locked; locked posts can't be voted on."

Looks like a bug to me. Please allow me to unfollow migrated questions.

[How do I unfollow a deleted question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/346423/256777) is related. (I also followed a deleted question, but for that, clicking "unfollow" worked.)

[This post has been locked; locked posts can't be voted on](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/349799/this-post-has-been-locked-locked-posts-cant-be-voted-on) has been proposed as a duplicate. It isn't: it states that "I can only unfollow it by going through the profile." I can *not* unfollow a migrated question in my profile.

[Cannot unfollow locked post from Following tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/349629/256777) describes the exact behavior I am having, just for deleted-as-spam questions instead of migrated ones. It may be that both questions can be addressed through the same underlying fix.

Comment: This is a specific case of [This post has been locked; locked posts can't be voted on](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/349799/this-post-has-been-locked-locked-posts-cant-be-voted-on) - migrated questions are locked on the origin site when migrated.

Comment: @SonictheMaskedWerehog: thanks, but the proposed duplicate explicitly says "I can only unfollow it by going through the profile." For a migrated question, I can *not* unfollow it from my profile page. So no duplicate.

Comment: This one is applicable, though: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/349629/cannot-unfollow-locked-post-from-following-tab

Comment: @SonictheMaskedWerehog: thanks, that one indeed exhibits the same behavior. It may be that one fix addresses both issues if it's two symptoms of the same underlying issue.