# Is the world's software better because of StackOverflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, experts-exchange

By any common definition of "better" -- fewer bugs, more interoperabilty, cleaner experience -- software seems to be better today than 10 years ago, and daily getting better.

I believe some of that comes from more capable hardware.  Some from more and faster Internet access.  Some from robust Open Source.  Some from Google.  And some from StackOverflow.

Common amongst those catalysts is information availablity.  Invention seems to materialize faster, and more diversely, in an information-rich atmosphere.  StackOverflow is about information-interchange.  But so is experts-exchange.  But would the world's software be where it is today if we only had experts-exchange....

Has StackOverflow made your software better?  Quanitfy.
Do you believe the world's software is better (or worse) similiarly?  Qualify.

Comment: Yeah, guess I am a Grinch.

Comment: awesome Grinchiness

Comment: Wow! Asked and closed the same minute

Comment: "Ho Ho Ho" Hat Ho.

Comment: @Oded *On hold your horses* !!

Comment: @Oded. Nah, I just didn't understand the [intent](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90515/please-add-discussion-as-a-close-reason-or-a-subset-of-not-a-real-question-o) or [meaning](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114744/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-discussion-tag-on-meta-stack-overflow) of the discussion tag.

Comment: @Oded: Though it does seem incongruent that a subjective question *about StackOverflow* is held (this one) while a [subjective question about programming is left open](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1971/what-is-the-worst-programming-language-discussion).

Comment: Not sure what you mean? The question you linked is a discussion about the suitability of a specific question to Stack Overflow (that question is actually closed **and** locked).

Comment: @Oded: The question I linked (which is open) was asking why a question on SO was closed. I suppose that isn't incongruent -- the title confused me.  Too much eggnog too early, I suppose.  Happy Holidays!